# how to get to convert a path to uri

Tags: android

Currently, my intention is to capture a video, and after that, i get a reference to the path of the video (this video is saved locally in storage file), then I save the path of video in a database and then when i want to play this video I convert this path to a URI and play the video.

this code explains my attempt at doing so:

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri videoUri = intent.getData();
        String path = videoUri.getPath();
        Uri uri2 = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        v.setVideoURI(uri2);
        v.start();
    }
}
```

where V is a **videoView**

when i try to set uri2 to the videoView (v) i get an error that i cannot play
 this video.

can anyone tell what i've done wrong.

Comment: Why are you not just using `videoUri`? Why are you attempting to convert an existing `Uri` (`videoUri`) to a `String`, then to a `File`, then to another `Uri`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried to abstract my attempt because I want to save the path(string) in a database then get this string back and convert it as a URI and play the video

Comment: "because i want to save the path(string) in a database" -- why not save the `Uri` in the database? After all, a `Uri` can be converted to and from a `String`. Have you looked at the `Uri`? What does the `Uri` look like? If the `Uri` has a `content` scheme, you may not be able to access the content in the future, anyway, as your read access to that content may lapse once your process terminates.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare that solved the problem by using 
  String s = videoUri.toString();
to convert the uri as a string then when i want it back i just use
        Uri mUri = Uri.parse(s);

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem with the help of  @CommonsWare suggestion to save the uri itself in the the database and this could be done using the following

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri videoUri = intent.getData();
        String s = videoUri.toString();
        Uri mUri = Uri.parse(s);
        v.setVideoURI(mUri);
        v.start();
    }
}
```